ESP32-S3-WROOM CAM development board is just showing a blank video on OV5640
I have successfully uploaded the code to the esp32-s3-wroom cam development board cam but whatever device or browser I use, when I press the start stream button it just shows a blank/picture icon. What could be the possible cause of this and how can I solve it?
I tested OV2640 camera that is working fine, but OV5640 is not working even I tested 2 OV5640 cameras

it could be almost anything ... start with checking electrical connections

Connections are right because the camera is connected to the esp32 board directly through the connector

Maybe the code is for OV2640 but does not support OV5640. Do they even use the same link speeds?

They both uses similar code
